# Accelerator character not shown for TPopupMenu items, a windows settings issue or what?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Well, this sounds a like newbie question, but somehow I couldn't get the [accelerator keys](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Specifying_Accelerator_Keys_and_Keyboard_Shortcuts) appears for the standard TPopupMenu items, how to fix that?

Below are two screenshots I created by creating a new VCL forms application without any coding.

Design time, **OK**:
[image]

Run time, no underlines:
[image]

The system is win7 Home with latest updates.

Answer (score 4):

This is the default behaviour of Windows. Accelerator keys are hidden so long as you interact with menus using the mouse. Once you start using the keyboard to interact with them then the accelerator keys will be displayed.

You can see this in action by invoking the menu using the popup menu key that is typically found to the right of the space bar. Alternatively <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> can be used to invoke the popup menu from the keyboard. Main menus behave in the same way, this is not limited to popup menus.

There is a Windows setting that allows this behaviour to be changed. This setting allows you to request that accelerator keys are always show, irrespective of how the menu was invoked.

Comment: Is this behavior new? I remember that on Windows XP accelerator characters were always shown even when you opened MainMenu or PopupMenu using mouse and not keyboard.

Comment: @Silver This behaviour was introduced in XP. Prior to then accel characters were always underlined. http://www.zeigen.com/shortcuts/2008/06/14/revealing-the-underlined-shortcut-configuring-windows-xp-to-be-more-keyboard-friendly/

Comment: I guess I might have custom configuration on my machine becouse I remember accelerator characters to be always seen. But then again my firs order alfter installing Windows XP was always ot change lots of system settings becouse this way you could further improve the system security and even stability. But I do not remember changing any setting related to accelerator characters. It ight have been changed by installing Slovenian language pack. Who knows.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I replied to you in the 'update 1' section of the original question above.

Comment: That's a new question. Easy enough to answer. But a new question all the same. I answered the original question.